# Testing Authentication For Self-Hosted WCF Service in an Integration Test

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I am trying to consume a self-hosted WCF application using SSL and a custom authentication validator from within an integration test.  So far I am able to self-host the service but I am not able to figure out how to consume it.

Here is the self-hosting code (it is not dependent on Web.Config, as far as I know):

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void TestClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
{
    const string serviceAddress = "https://localhost/SelfHostedService";
    Uri _svcEndpointUri = new Uri(serviceAddress);
    var binding = new WSHttpBinding
    {
        Security =
        {
            Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential,
            Message = {ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName}
        }
    };
    ServiceDebugBehavior debugBehavior = new ServiceDebugBehavior
    {
        IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
    };
    MyServiceApi _api = new MyServiceApi();
    ServiceHost _svcHost = new ServiceHost(_api, _svcEndpointUri);
    _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Remove<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(debugBehavior);

    // Ensure that SSL certificate & authentication interceptor get used
    ServiceCredentials credentials = new ServiceCredentials();
    credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
    credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = new MyCustomAuthenticationValidator();
    credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "SubjectName");
    _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Remove<ServiceCredentials>();
    _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(credentials);

    // Add IUbiquity and mex endpoints
    Uri endpointAddress = new Uri(serviceAddress + "/UbiquityApi.svc");
    _svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof (IUbiquityApi), binding, endpointAddress);


    // Specify InstanceContextMode, which is required to self-host
    var behavior = _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
    behavior.InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single;
    _svcHost.Open();
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do looks like this, but I have no idea how I'd go about accomplish this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestAuthentication(){
    var api = _svcHost.MagicallyRetrieveServiceInstance();
    api.Credentials = new MagicCredentials("my username", "my password");
    Assert.AreEqual(3, api.AddNumbers(1,2));
    // Also assert that I am authenticated 

    api.Credentials = new MagicCredentials("my username", "my password");
    bool exceptionWasThrown = false;
    try {
       api.AddNumbers(1,2);
    }
    catch(NotLoggedInException l){ // or something
       exceptionWasThrown = true;
    }
    Assert.IsTrue(exceptionWasThrown);
}
```

My ideal solution would allow me to retrieve the service contract from the service host, and allow me to set the credentials used for the service contract.  I should only have to supply the credentials once to the service contract, and then I should be able to call methods directly, as if I were communicating over the wire (thus making this an integration test).  How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To consume the web service, simply add the service as a service reference, and then use the service reference client.

Done right, this will take care of the bindings needed for authentication, effectively putting the WCF configurations under test.